# Parsing SOAP xml using RaptureXML parser

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I am working with an iOS application. I need to parse some SOAP XML responses. I am using
RaptureXML parser. It shows empty  in "loginResponse" when i parse the XML.

```
 RXMLElement *rootXML = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLString:xmlString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


 RXMLElement *loginResponse = [rootXML child:@"loginResponse"];
```

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soapcom" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <loginResponse>
         <result>
            <metadataServerUrl>https://um7/services/Soap/m/37.0/00D58000000Zj7H</metadataServerUrl>
            <passwordExpired>false</passwordExpired>
            <sandbox>false</sandbox>
            <serverUrl>https://um7/services/Soap/u/37.0/00D58000000Zj7H</serverUrl>
            <sessionId>123456</sessionId>
            <userId>123456</userId>
            <userInfo>
               <accessibilityMode>false</accessibilityMode>
               <currencySymbol>£</currencySymbol>
               <userUiSkin>Theme3</userUiSkin>
            </userInfo>
         </result>
      </loginResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: The node `loginResponse` is not a child node of `rootXML`. So you need some additional steps: `rootXML-> Envelope -> Body -> loginResponse`.

Comment: If you have `wsdl` file I would recommend to generate soap client at http://sudzc.com